# CSS - Is it possible to set a border-bottom to be the same size of a class it isn't associated with?

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to set a `border-bottom` to be the same size of a class it isn't associated with?

for instance I want a `border-bottom` at the bottom of every `<section>` tag. but the sections width is the full width of the screen there for the `border-bottom` inherits that size.

Every `<section>` contains a `<div class="container">` and I need my `border-bottom` to match that sizing to only underline the content width within that `<section>`

My closest attempt was:

```
section{
   .container:first-child{
     border-bottom: 2px solid red;
   }
}
```

But I didn't get the desired outcome due to those containers closing before the end of the content etc.

there can also be multiple containers in a `<section>` so I can't just add it to `container`

NOTE: 
scss options are also appreciated if there are any.

I also can't add border to the `container` class. It needs to be strictly added to the `<section>` tag. (I'm pretty sure this is due to wordpress loops looping the same `container` multiple times and the css still reading it as a single container because there may only be one in the source code) <- not sure if thats entirely true but its the only way the outcome of doing so makes sense.

[check the fiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/2wmd7tjn/)

Comment: a bit confused about your explanation of what you're going for. what's wrong with just applying an additional class to any `container` class you want a border for?

Comment: Is it possible via javascript? sure. Anything you set your mind to is possible to manipulate in the DOM with javascript. Is it possible to solve this by adding an additional class to the outer element and to the inner element? sure, that's a simple solution. 

HTML is structure. css is styling. JS is manipulation. What you need to do is manage your result. good luck!

Comment: there are a couple reasons. one this is code is auto generated from a wordpress template. also the first `container` may also end half way through the content leading to another `container`. its not consistantly the first one that wraps all the content. So my idea was to try and match the border-bottom under `<section>` to have the same width as `container`

Comment: @LongChalk its possible but not preferred. this is a wordpress template that I should be able to make all minor changes just in the .css file. for future productivity I should only be adding css and scss.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle? According to your current question you should just apply the `border-bottom` style to `container` as I assume it is the `width` of your content or why would that not work?

Comment: @cray I cant add it to `container` because there can be multiple in a `<section>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a line under the last `container` element in a section. Use `:last-child` selector to achieve that. If there are `container` elements inside `container` elements use `>` to select only direct children of `section`.

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
}
.body-wrap {
  display:flex;
}
.container {
  width: 100px;
}
section > .container:last-child {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
.container2 {
  width: 100px;
}
section .container2:last-child {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-wrap">
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Border on last direct child</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    SOME
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    SOME
    <p>TEXT</p>
    <div class="container">
    SOME
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container2">
    Border on last child
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <p>Will be duplicated when last-child has .container2 inside it</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    SOME
    <p>TEXT</p>
    <div class="container2">
    SOME
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats close but I dont think I can add the border on the container at all. I need it strictly on the section

Comment: Explain the reason why it can not be on container

Comment: I believe it has to do with the wordpress loops. it can cause me to have multiple `last-child` containers if that makes any sense. because the code may have one container but that container ends up being created multiple times through a loop. I end up getting multiple `border-bottom`'s in the same section

Comment: Are there containers appended to container as in container inside a container? Because in that case you will get double border, but if the section is a direct parent of every container there will be one border only.

Comment: Edited with solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

So far I came out you can only edit CSS/SCSS.

You can try `:nth-child()` .

Check this link : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think this one line of code can solve your probelm

```
section{
   .container:first-child{
     border-bottom: 2px solid red;
     box-sizing:border-box
   }
}
```

Comment: sorry I can't add it to the container this way because of the wordpress loops

Comment: just added that to my question